# problem with authentication with accessToken and refreshToken

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, laravel-passport

I want to login and send post and ... with react and laravel passport.
but I have `access_token` and `refresh_token` . when I should use `access_token` and when I should use `refresh_token` ?

Please explain me with code

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If your access token expires, you can make your next request using the refresh token instead, which will then send a new access token to React and will allow your user to continue using your app without authenticating again.